# Can you reserve your token name and symbol before releasing to mainnet?

Tags: contract-development, remix, tokens, contract-deployment, crowdsale

Is it possible to list our token to reserve the name and symbol before our contracts are released on mainnet?

Comment: Anyone can copy the name and Symbol of any token and try to scam people with. So it is your job to make sure that the people know exactly which contract address belong to your token

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, there isn't a centralized registry for token names or symbols.